# how to pass code as an object key value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a little bit of a two part question.  #1 How do you do it and #2 should it be done.

I am building a modal which two sections, a tabs section and a content section.  When I click a new tab the content section should change accordingly.

I want to pass data to my component in the form of an array of objects.

For example:

```
tabData = [{title: Tab 1, content: `${<div>Content</div>}`}]
```

I am not exactly sure how to pass code in the contents of my object.  Is this something that can be done?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Sounds like you need a store both can tap into

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if the code is a string then maybe you could try this:

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: '<div>Content</div>' }} />`

Do **check/sanitize** the code.